# How to send Array of WhatsApp messages in a sequence

Tags: node.js, arrays, api, sequence, whatsapp

I am developing a WhatsApp bot using [WATI](https://docs.wati.io/reference/introduction) and Node.js

I have an array of messages for eg:

```
module_split = ["msg 1","msg 2", "msg 3"]
```

I want to send each element of array one by one in a sequence on WhatsApp. But I am not able achieve that. I tried using setTimeout()

```
module_split.forEach(msg => {
                    console.log("4. module split ")

                    setTimeout(async () => {
                        await WA.sendText(msg, number).then().catch(e => console.log("Error sending text ", e))
                    }, 30000)

                });
```

The elements are randomly being sent everytime with different order. I want to send msg 1 first, than msg 2 and so on. Is there a way I achieve this?

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: you should not use await on Promise.then(). Is setTimeout() your requirement? So you want to run your code sequentially but also with each message you want to wait some time and send next message?

Comment: Also what I see is the WATI provides REST API endpoints and could not find any official nodejs library. So `WA.sendText` is your custom function?

Comment: Yes, with each message I want to wait sometime and send the next message.

And yes, I just created a function sendText that uses WATI endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `Promise.then()` with `await`

`for...of` can be used to run asynchronous calls sequentially using `try-catch` and `await` syntax as follows:

```js
// this asynchronous function will wait for delay in ms
const awaitTimeout = delay => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay));

for (const msg of module_split)
{
   try {
      console.log("4. module split ")
      await awaitTimeout(2000) // wait for 2s
      await WA.sendText(msg, number)
   } catch (e) {
      console.log("Error sending text ", e)
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the messages are still being sent randomly, is there a way I can add delay between the elements of the array?

Comment: @DummyCron Can you add the implementation of `WA.sendText` in your question, I feel they should not be random with the above implementation

Comment: Just added a delay in my implementation, I am not sure why it is in random order for you, the implementation might be wrong for `WA.sendText`

Comment: I tried this, but in my case when I divide the messages into several to send the same response to the same user, it happens to me that it stays in a loop. Trying to send the same response on more than one occasion. Verifying the behavior of the webhook I notice that the user's message goes in and goes in again and again and again. I read in the documentation that you must return a 200 status to ensure that the received message has been answered. I've tried a bit of everything but the behavior remains the same, I have a question posted on the subject, I don't know what else to try

Comment: Only in my case I'm just using whatsapp api directly in nodejs